# What's the most effective way to get Dark Elixir?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Ok, so I am trying to max out all of my Dark Elixir troops. My problem is, my Town Hall is maxed (Level 10) and it takes forever for me to get any substantial amount of loot from anybody. My Collectors are all level 3. What's the most effective way to get Dark Elixir in a short amount of time?

Comment: how many trophies do you have?

Comment: @Jeffmagma 2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry for myself not being clear last time, the fact is that when you are going to score dark elixir and save it u should do following things

1. firstly, (an easy one) make a base that protects de at the centre with a lot of splash damages around
2. normally peole use barchers but i recommend(if u have a capacity of 200) using 60 barbarian, 60 archers, 4 giants, 8 wallbreakers, and 44 goblins, and use three lightning spells

Strategy: take the lightning spells to damages at least on or( if near) more of the splash damage objects (like, wiz tower, mortars) and the clear up the others by distracting the defenses with giants and handling them with barchers, after all the  splash damage defenses has been taken out, now u dont need to fear so, leave all of the troops at once, and they will sure get all the loot

remember: Never set out all the barchers or goblin troops when there are still splash damage objects around and especially goblins

relation to dark elixir: the relation od=f this strategy with dark elixir is that, even if u come across a very strong base but u can still use the lightning spell to grab some dark elixir from the storage and use few of the barchers to take something from the pump, i did the same until i had taken my heroes to lvl 5

Answer (score 1):

Barching and skipping all bases with empty collectors/drills on the outside and raiding all the abandoned bases where the layout sux and the collectors are all full.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most effective way of getting dark elixir is by raiding a base with 100+ archers or 100+ barbarians and 1 healing spell and 2 lightning spells. Giants will not help get dark elixir because they go after the defences fist and they don't destroy something as fast as a archer or a barbarian. And this might lose you some trophies but I think it is worth it. Know whats weird I don't have a Dark elixir pump I just use the method above.

Answer (score 0):

My stratergy is better i think which is of 200 capacity. Take 50Barbs, 70Arch, 30Minnion, 5Wb, 10Gobs, King lvl 5 or plus. 2light, 1heal.

Stratergy:- Use Arch and some minnions to clear out the outer buildings destroy any mortar or wiz tower which is near de storage by 2 lightning. Use wb to break the walls then send 50 barbs with king the ability of king will give thrm rage (boost) then if the other splash defence lowers theur health the healing will protect them for a long time. While barbs and king are clearing the defences use minnions, arch and gobs. The defences will not be able to handle these troops because their focus is on king and barbs u will destroy the de storage and may even get 50% to 80% on the enemy !

Answer (score 0):

Now I am in th9 but I hardly find dark elixirs and I don't even upgrade my golem and valkyrie. So they are still level one. I use many ways but I didn't find any effective ways to find dark elixir fast. Now I am using 20 giants, one healer, 6 wall breakers, 18 wizards, one rage spell, and two healing spells.
That way it is easy to find both loot and trophies.
Mostly, I attack only the bases who have over 300000 gold and elixir, and 1000 dark elixir.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than a full blown answer, but not having played the game I can't say for sure

Answer (score 0):

I have an army with 5giants 3wb 7balloons 6wiz 2zaps 1heal

I drop giants to distract the splash damage and then I deploy wizards to get dark elixir then heal giants when air defence is gone deploy balloons. Works for th8

Answer (score -1):

Come on.  The most effective way of getting dark elixir is to pay for it.  Buy the gems and fill your storage.  Then use it for what you want before it gets looted by your opponents. Make sure you use fill your storage, as the other gem buys are a rip off.

Answer (score -1):

One idea would be to buy gems, then buy a shield, then boost your drills. I use this trick all the time.

Comment: Buying and using gems pretty much gives you an advantage on almost all parts of CoC.

Comment: Raiding is the fastest way to go. If a player raids day and night, while another is hiding behind his shield, the raiding player will come out with the most profit, considering that they're on all the time and not being raided themselves or using the dark Elixir in their army.